# windows explorer cant see files written by c# app File.WriteAllLines

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am having a strange problem that I am unable to access files written by my c# application. My app basically does :

```
var file = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\something.txt";
List<string> content = new List<string> { "one thing", "two things" };
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.Exists(file));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, content);
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.Exists(file));
```

The first time I run the app, the output is

```
False
True
```

Yet I cannot see the written file in Windows Explorer (Windows 10). I get no exceptions attempting to write the file. The second time I run the app, the output is :

```
True
True
```

According to my application the file is being written however Windows thinks differently. As a sanity check I spun up a second app that opens a dialog using OpenFileDialog. When I run that, I am able to see my written files! Windows explorer still cannot. Attached is a screenshot of windows explorer and my openfiledialog side by side.

If I go to notepad and browse for the file I cannot see it or manually type in the name.

Its been a long week of work, there must be some dumb explanation...? Help! :-)

Screenshot - windows explorer on left, c# app open dialog on right :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wiRc.jpg

Comment: Does it appear if you refresh the directory, or navigate out of the directory and back in?  I've seen that a lot with File Explorer in Windows 10 where it doesn't automatically update the contents of the selected directory to reflect changes and needs a little manual prodding before doing so.

Comment: Do your files happen to show up in (subfolders of) `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore` in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Have you powered it off and on again?

Comment: `C:\Users\Public\Documents` is actually `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents`. Your file is there.

Comment: @BACON unfortunately not. ive tried refreshing, rebooting dev machine, etc. i noticed this problem a while ago (maybe a couple months) so it has been an ongoing issue for a while now. i have been avoiding / not given attention to until now

Comment: @BradleyGrainger no, the files dont appear there.

Comment: @Jawad have definitely restarted my dev machine many times, i noticed this problem months ago and never sat down to diagnose until now

Comment: @Jimi unfortunately no, the files are not there. the location that i attempt to write the files does not matter. ive tried c:\users\[myusername]\desktop which is the first location I tried. also simpler paths like c:\temp\ exhibit same behavior : files do not appear in windows explorer but i can see them via the open file dialog within my app

Comment: Are Explorer and your application (and the `OpenFileDialog` application) running under the exact same access token?  If you're logged in as a member of `Administrators` but you're running your application elevated, too, I could see that causing a disparity, though I'd expect it to be more along the lines of the file being visible-but-not-accessible instead of not-visible.  Otherwise, do you have any Explorer extensions installed?  Antivirus you could try temporarily disabling?

Comment: @BACON it was the comodo anti-virus we are required to use. im not yet sure the exact behavior andor how to grant my apps proper permission to write files while it is enabled. but after disabling the antivirus and restarting my app i am able to write and see the files. i think the antivirus (when enabled) is putting them in some kind of container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per @BACON 's suggestion in the comments above I discovered that after disabling the Comodo anti-virus I am able to write and see my files.

I believe the software is running my app or either only allowing IO from my app in some kind of container. I need to figure out how to grant my apps proper permissions through the anti-virus software, but that was the culprit.